# Testing for a common word between 2 strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, pattern-matching

I have to match 2 strings where at least one word is same, I need to give a success msg.

```
var str1 = "Hello World";
var str2 = "world is beautiful";
```

I need to match/compare these 2 strings, in both strings world is matching, So i need to print a success message. How do I go about it.

Comment: complete word or partial word?  Should "worldly" match "world" or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will output all the matching words in the both strings:

```
var words1 = str1.split(/\s+/g),
    words2 = str2.split(/\s+/g),
    i,
    j;

for (i = 0; i < words1.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < words2.length; j++) {
        if (words1[i].toLowerCase() == words2[j].toLowerCase()) {
           console.log('word '+words1[i]+' was found in both strings');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To explain the bare code a bit, we are getting the two lists of individual words, and comparing each word in the first list to each word in the second. This will require O(n^2) comparisons for an average word count n.

Comment: You might want to add a `i++` and `break` to your if statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid comparing all the words in one list with all the words in the other by sorting each and eliminating duplicates. Adapting [bjornd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13413417/36537):

```
var words1 = str1.split(/\s+/g),
    words2 = str2.split(/\s+/g);

var allwords = {};
// set 1 for all words in words1
for(var wordid=0; wordid < words1.length; ++wordid) {
    var low = words1[wordid].toLowerCase();
    allwords[low] = 1;
}
// add 2 for all words in words2
for(var wordid=0; wordid < words2.length; ++wordid) {
    var current = 0;
    var low = words2[wordid].toLowerCase();
    if(allwords.hasOwnProperty(low)) {
        if(allwords[low] > 1) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    current += 2;
    allwords[low] = current;
}
// now those seen in both lists have value 3, the rest either 1 or 2.
// this is effectively a bitmask where the unit bit indicates words1 membership
// and the 2 bit indicates words2 membership
var both = [];
for(var prop in allwords) {
    if(allwords.hasOwnProperty(prop) && (allwords[prop] == 3)) {
        both.push(prop);
    }
}
```

This version should be reasonably efficient, because we are using a dictionary/hash structure to store information about each set of words. The whole thing is O(n) in javascript expressions, but inevitably dictionary insertion is not, so expect something like O(n log n) in practise. If you only care that a single word matches, you can quit early in the second for loop; the code as-is will find all matches.

This is broadly equivalent to sorting both lists, reducing each to unique words, and then looking for pairs in both lists. In C++ etc you would do it via two sets, as you could do it without using a dictionary and the comparison would be O(n) after the sorts. In Python because it's easy to read:

```
words1 = set(item.lower() for item in str1.split())
words2 = set(item.lower() for item in str2.split())
common = words1 & words2
```

The sort here (as with any set) happens on insertion into the set O(n log n) on word count n, and the intersection (&) is then efficent O(m) on the set length m.

Comment: Whoa, talking about premature optimization... ;) Nevertheless nice answer

Comment: @WTK: Yes, it's overkill if you have a few words in a string, but you never know whether the asker wants to do this with long strings, or whether someone else will see this question when solving their own (larger) problem. I didn't want to leave bjornd's answer on its own as it is O(n^2) and for finding complete sets of common words it would be significantly more costly. And it is fun to do these things.

Comment: Sure, sure - I didn't mean to criticize. I agree that you never know for what people may be looking so it's good to provide variety of good answers :)

Comment: @WTK: Indeed. I didn't mean to suggest you were wrong to point that out, it's definitely overkill most of the time, particularly in javascript where you're unlikely to meet the large n!

Answer (score 1):

Just adapting @Phil H's code with a real bitmask:

```
var strings = ["Hello World", "world is beautiful"]; // up to 32 word lists
var occurrences = {},
    result = [];
for (var i=0; i<strings.length; i++) {
    var words = strings[i].toLowerCase().split(/\s+/),
        bit = 1<<i;
    for (var j=0, l=words.length; j<l; j++) {
        var word = words[j];
        if (word in occurrences)
            occurrences[word] |= bit;
        else
            occurrences[word] = bit;
    }
}
// now lets do a match for all words which are both in strings[0] and strings[1]
var filter = 3; // 1<<0 | 1<<1
for (var word in occurrences)
    if ((occurrences[word] & filter) === filter)
        result.push(word);
```

Comment: Why don´t you assign the 3 directly?

Comment: @Amberlamps: Sure, makes no difference. Just wanted to indicate how it was constructed

Comment: @Bergi: Niiice. I guess for more strings you could do this for groups of 32 strings, and then `&` the groups together, with a multi-stage check for the final comparison. Or use `i/32` to index into lists as the values of `occurences`. BTW occu*rr*ence has 2 rs.

Comment: @PhilH: Thanks for the hint, still growing my English :) Btw, fractions won't work as JS does all bit operations on 32-bit-integers

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this on [WriteCodeOnline](http://writecodeonline.com/javascript/) and it works there:

```
var s1 = "hello world, this is me";
var s2 = "I am tired of this world and I want to get off";
var s1s2 = s1 + ";" + s2;
var captures = /\b(\w+)\b.*;.*\b\1\b/i.exec(s1s2);

if (captures[1])
{
   document.write(captures[1] + " occurs in both strings");
}
else
{
  document.write("no match in both strings");
}
```

Comment: Cool!  Even semi-colons are safe, thanks to greedy matching! +1!

Comment: A drawback of this method is having to pick a separator string that is known not to occur in any of the lines. Also, I'm not sure whether `\1` back references and `\b` word boundary matching are supported everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the simple way:

```
function isMatching(a, b)
{
  return new RegExp("\\b(" + a.match(/\w+/g).join('|') + ")\\b", "gi").test(b);
}

isMatching("in", "pin"); // false
isMatching("Everything is beautiful, in its own way", "Every little thing she does is magic"); // true
isMatching("Hello World", "world is beautiful"); // true
```

...understand?

I basically converted `"Hello, World!"` to the regular expression `/\b(Hello|World)\b/gi`

Comment: ... Then I noticed @reinierpost already kind of did it this way!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would also do:

```
isMatching = function(str1, str2) {
    str2 = str2.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0, words = str1.toLowerCase().match(/\w+/g); i < words.length; i++) {
        if (str2.search(words[i]) > -1) return true;
    } 
    return false;
};

var str1 = "Hello World";
var str2 = "world is beautiful";
isMatching(str1, str2); // returns true
isMatching(str1, 'lorem ipsum'); // returns false
```

Comment: @madhu: This will match "in" with "pin" for example, no?